# Update MYSQL date field with the use of SELECT query in combination with FROM_UNIXTIME and SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql

*Disclaimer: I am trying to avoid solution where I updated a new field with the result of the `SUBSTRING` function and then add another field that uses the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function.*

I need to convert the following string in the table `METRIC` and field `CIS_DATE2` in MYSQL
to  `date` format.

INPUT is `CIS DATE2` and desired output is `CIS_DATE`.

`CIS_DATE` is empty and should be UPDATED with the SELECT query as below.

| CIS_DATE2 | CIS_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1154390400000000000 | 2006-08-01 |
| 1154390400000000000 | 2006-08-01 |
| 1154390400000000000 | 2006-08-01 |
| 1154390400000000000 | 2006-08-01 |

The SELECT query showing the correct result:

```
select from_unixtime(SUBSTRING(`CIS_DATE2`,1,10),'%Y-%m-%d') from metric;
```

Example of the UPDATE query that returns the error `Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

```
update METRIC
   set `CIS_DATE` = (
      select from_unixtime(SUBSTRING(`CIS_DATE2`,1,10),'%Y-%m-%d') from (
         select * from METRIC
      ) as x
      where `CIS_DATE2` is not null);
```

OR

```
update METRIC set `CIS_DATE` = (select from_unixtime(SUBSTRING(`CIS_DATE2`,1,10),'%Y-%m-%d')) 
WHERE `CIS_DATE2` is not null;
```

Comment: Your last query works fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Y9NHBEMUU71YnYR3cT35m/0 although it can be simplified: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Y9NHBEMUU71YnYR3cT35m/1

Comment: To me it throws an error `Error Code: 1366. Incorrect DECIMAL value: '0' for column '' at row -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The case of `Error Code: 1366. Incorrect DECIMAL value: '0' for column '' at row -1` means that the conversion from the NULL or '' value is not possible. To avoid this, the UPDATE query should be as follows:

```
update METRIC set `CIS_DATE` = (select from_unixtime(SUBSTRING(`CIS_DATE2`,1,10),'%Y-%m-%d')) 
WHERE `CIS_DATE2` is not null AND `CIS_DATE2` <> '';
```